# 'A center of' or 'a center for'?

Tags: prepositions

> a centre ***of*** academic excellence
>
> a centre ***for*** academic excellence

Would you please throw an example show me what is the difference between those?

Many thanks

Comment: As far as I know, both are correct. **Centre of academic excellence** and **Centre for Academic Excellence**. Though the use of **for** here is not so common, and mostly used with some names. [This graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=centre+of%2C+centre+for&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccentre%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccentre%20for%3B%2Cc0) will show the comparison.

Comment: A priori (without looking for relative prevalence of usage), I would interpret a "Center **of** Excellence" as a locus that had been recognized by outside parties as being excellent in whatever it does. I would read "Center **for**Excellence" as a self-named center for the **purpose** of promoting/fomenting/rewarding excellence in what other people do (presumably the other divisions of the institution that established the Center.) But people can name intitutes however they wish.

Comment: Compare, for example, National Intitute of Mental Health (NIMH) and the Center**s** for Disease Control [and Prevention] (CDC). or the National Association for the advancement of Colored People (NAACP) and the NAM (National Association of Manufacturers)

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_excellence) defines *center of excellence* as:

> a team, a shared facility or an entity that provides leadership, evangelization, best practices, research, support and/or training for a technology, a business concept, a skill, or a broad area of study.

[Here is an Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=center+of+excellence%2Ccenter+for+excellence&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) that contrasts the usage of *center **of** excellence* vs *center **for** excellence*. From this, I think we can conclude two things:

- Centers of excellence are trending – that is, universities and other organizations are founding new ones all the time.
- Somewhere along the way (perhaps in the mid-1970s?), some folks decided that *for* might be a better preposition to use than *of*.

What is the difference between the two? I don't think there is any, except in name and name alone. Near as I can tell, the Wikipedia definition of *center of excellence* would apply to a center **for** excellence.

It's worth noting that [*for*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/for) and [*of*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/of) can be used interchangeably at times. Both prepositions have several meanings, and a few of them overlap. For example, I can say:

> According to Macmillan's definition **of** 'center of excellence'

or:

> According to Macmillan's definition **for** 'center of excellence'

So why would an organization pick *for* rather than *of*, when *of* is more common? I can think of two possible reasons:

1. Some might consider *for* to be a more "active" preposition, while *of* is a more "passive" preposition. (You don't campaign *of* a cause, you campaign *for* a cause.) A university's center for teaching excellence is not a static entity – it's trying to promote good teaching within the institution.
2. Some might think that the term *center of excellence* could be a little ambiguous. [One dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/center-of-excellence) defines the term as, quite simply, "a place where there are very high standards of work". Also, one [medical dictionary](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/center+of+excellence) rather disdainfully mentions that *center of excellence* is "a colloquial, jargonistic, and vastly overused term."

This is one of those areas that a learner might agonize over, while a native speaker would neither give much thought to which preposition was chosen, nor discern any significant difference in meaning between a *Center of Academic Excellence* and a *Center for Academic Excellence*.

Answer (score -2):

Good question. I searched the phrases and found that **both** are in practice.

> Regent Oxford is a **centre of academic excellence** for which we have been renowned locally and internationally since we were established in 1953 - *[Regent English Language Training](http://www.regent.org.uk/)*

And...

> National, state and local officials praised the University of South Alabama’s School of Computing as USA announced on Feb. 11 its continuing designation as a **Center for Academic Excellence** in Information Assurance and Cyber Defense from the U.S. National Security Agency and the Department of Homeland Security. - *[University of South Alabama](http://www.southalabama.edu/departments/publicrelations/pressreleases/02111SOCdesignation.html)*

And...

> We have **a center for academic excellence** that we intend to roll out.... - *[a statement in Washington Post.](http://www.washingtonpost.com/local/education/qanda-with-howards-new-interim-president/2013/10/20/5189faca-36c1-11e3-8a0e-4e2cf80831fc_story.html)*

It's worth noting that string *"...**for** academic excellence..."* shows **no** results on Ngram. And I tried both the spellings -*center* and *centre*.

Personally, I'd prefer ***'of'*** over ***'for'***.

Comment: Actually, we should "prefer" is the one that most accurately conveys what we intend to convey. The numbers on the Ngram are very small – too small to say that "for" is the wrong choice, particularly when Googling ["center for * excellence"](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=%22center+for++*+excellence%22&start=180) returns countless hits.

Comment: @J.R. true but we often advise people that Google can bring all the results from everywhere including articles/blogs written by non-native speakers. It does give results on 'loose weight' as well. Considering Ngram and other authentic sources, I wrote 'prefer'. Locally as well, I have come across 'of' and rarely 'for'.

Comment: This question is a good one; several organizations opt to use _for_, while others use _of_. You've ended your answer with _because «for academic excellence» shows no results on Ngram .. This means, we should prefer 'of' over 'for'_ . That's bad advice, for two reasons: (1) It ignores hundreds of centers **for** excellence that are easily found on Google, and (2) it promotes to the false belief that following an Ngram will lead a learner to select the right word. I applaud you for the research effort, but I strongly disagree with your conclusion from it.

Comment: @J.R. edited. Yes, personally, I also prefer 'of' over 'for'.

Comment: @J.R. and Maulik: I agree with J.R. We should all be more careful when drawing conclusions based on results from corpora. Also, in relation to our case, searching for `center * excellence` on Google Ngram shows results of both *of* and *for*.

Comment: @DamkerngT. - Especially when we forget that Ngrams are [case-dependent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Center+for+Academic+Excellence%2CCenter+of+Acedemic+Excellence&year_start=1980&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3)!

Comment: Hi J.R.! J.R., it seems to me that Damkerng and Maulik are your good friends? Can I join your group???Sorry, let's talk about the OP's question. I could not figure out why Maulik's answer got so many downVote. Maulik's answer is alright, I think his answer is ok from my perspective, although my English is bad.